# Split string from one point to another (different delimiters)

Tags: python, regex, split

I want to split this string `def Hello(self,event):` so that only `Hello` is left, the delimiter would first be `def` and then I guess `():`. How can I do this in python?

Comment: Have you tried using regular expressions?

Comment: Hm, why do you want to use ``split`` to do this? Doesn't seem appropriate...

Comment: You need to describe **how** it should leave only '`Hello'`...

Comment: >>> s.split('def ')[1].split('(')[0]
'Hello'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using Regular Expressions for something like this (see the other examples), but to answer your question here is the solution using `split`:

```
In [1]: str = "def Hello(self,event):"
In [2]: str.split(' ')[1].split('(')[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like

```
re.findall('^def ([^(]+)', 'def Hello(self, asdf):')
```

Comment: @Ωmega I just like going to the end sometimes.

Comment: Okay, it is still good, just not optimized for performance :)

Comment: @Ωmega Fine.. I'll put the speed holes in the hood. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use regex pattern

```
^def\s+(\w+)\((.*?)\)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using regular expressions:

```
import re
re.search(r'def\s+([^)\s]*)\s*\(', your_string).group(1)
```

Examples:

```
>>> re.search(r'def\s+([^)\s]*)\s*\(', 'def Hello(self, asdf):').group(1)
'Hello'
>>> re.search(r'def\s+([^)\s]*)\s*\(', 'def  Hello  (self, asdf):').group(1)
'Hello'
```

Explanation:

```
def         # literal string 'def'
\s+         # one or more whitespace characters
(           # start capture group 1
  [^)\s]*     # any number of characters that are not whitespace or '('
)           # end of capture group 1
\s*         # zero or more whitespace characters
\(          # opening parentheses
```